# Prawn (Ruby) - How to use :inline_format <color rgb=""></color>, but still keep the text stroke?

Tags: ruby, prawn

I know, looking at the Prawn manual that you can draw inline text as "stroked", like this (from the manual):

```
fill_color "00ff00"
stroke_color "0000ff"

font_size(40) do
  # normal rendering mode: fill
  text "This text is filled with green."
  move_down 20

  # inline rendering mode: stroke
  text "This text is stroked with blue", :mode => :stroke
  move_down 20

  # block rendering mode: fill and stroke
  text_rendering_mode(:fill_stroke) do
    text "This text is filled with green and stroked with blue"
  end
```

And I also know that you have some control over inline formatting, like this:

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa <color rgb="xxxxxx">UP</color> aaaaaaaa"
```

But now the "UP" isn't outlined as it should be.

How do I outline text and use inline_formatting? Can I?

Here is an example of something I've attempted:

```
require 'prawn'

class SomeDoc < Prawn::Document
    def initialize
        super({:margin => [5,5], :page_size => 'A4'})
    end

    def draw_text
        the_text = "the word <color rgb='74B743'>DOWN</color> should be a different color and be outlined"

        text_rendering_mode(:fill_stroke) do
            stroke_color "000000"
            fill_color "FFFFFF"
            text(the_text, :inline_format => true)
        end
    end
end

test = SomeDoc.new
test.draw_text
test.render_file('test.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pdf.text_rendering_mode(:fill_stroke) do
  pdf.stroke_color "431CEF"
  pdf.text("Outlined Text")
end
```

Instead of stroke_color you have to do:

```
pdf.stroke_color
```

Comment: Hi, I've been playing around with this. But I don't think this will work.. I've added some code though as an example